# Using PHP ini_set "memory_limit" safely

Tags: php, memory, optimization, memory-management, load

I currently have a script that is going to be running for quite a long time (forked in its own separate process though). It's not going to be running very often but when it does it's going to use quite a large amount of memory mainly in the processing of (many) XLS files (> 10 MB).

I currently have memory limit set to 1024M when this script is running with time limit of 6000 seconds. These are upper limit, however, in reality it doesn't take that much time (probably just 5 minutes is enough).

Because huge amount of memory is required I am wondering how PHP/Apache manages the memory.

- Is the memory freed automatically when the script terminates? If not, when will it be.
- Do I need to implicitly free objects?
- Is it possible to free memory a little bit at a time from within the script
- Is 1024M too much, how is it going to affect the server in the long run.

I am using PHPExcel Library by the way.

Comment: Use this function to determine how much memory script realy needs http://php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php (i mean, to debug in order to select optimal value for memory_limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer:

PHP uses reference counting, so objects are freed as soon as they are not referenced. If a reference cycle exists (e.g. object A references object B, which references object A), the garbage collector takes care of them from time to time.

When the script ends, all remaining memory is returned to the system.

## Long answer:

> Is the memory freed automatically when the script terminates? If not, when will it be.

The memory is freed during the script execution, as soon as objects/variables are not referenced anymore.

If for some reason objects are still referenced at the end of the script, they are forcibly destructed and freed.

And then, the memory allocator is reset (which frees few amounts of remaining allocated memory, like the allocator's own cache).

So at the end of the script, everything is freed and available for allocation again.

If the allocator uses `mmap()` to allocate memory segments internally (which is the default when mmap() is available), then de-allocations of big blocks, and reset of the memory allocator also return the memory to the system.

> Do I need to implicitly free objects?

No. Just make sure that the [garbage collector is enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.zend.enable-gc), so that reference cycles are taken care of.

> Is it possible to free memory a little bit at a time from within the script

PHP uses reference counting, and frees objects as soon as they are not referenced anymore:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a = null; // the object is freed at this point

function foo () {
    $a = new stdClass;
    return; // the object referenced by $a is freed at this point
}
```

Collecting reference cycles [manually](http://php.net/gc_collect_cycles) may free some memory earlier, although it's usually not necessary.

> Is 1024M too much, how is it going to affect the server in the long run.

If you run this memory-heavy script in a separate process, this won't affect the server.